# Invalid location coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have two coordinates:

```
@property (assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
@property (assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2;
```

During init I'm making them invalid (to be able to check later if it was set):

```
_coordinate1 = kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid;
_coordinate2 = kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid;
```

And then in method i check if they're valid:

```
- (void)checkIfValid {
    BOOL coordinatesAreValid = (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(_coordinate1) && CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(_coordinate2));
    NSAssert(coordinatesAreValid, @"You didn't set up coordinates!");
}
```

Before i call the method, i set these coordinates via this way:

```
[_myclassinstance setCoordinate1:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.region.center.longitude, mapView.region.center.latitude)];
[_myclassinstance setCoordinate2:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.region.center.longitude, mapView.region.center.latitude)];
[_myclassinstance checkIfValid];
```

The problem is that an app claims, the coordinates are wrong. I've printed them, they seem to be ok:

```
(lldb) p _coordinate1
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) $1 = {
  latitude = -122.4612387012154
  longitude = 37.72925050874177
}
(lldb) p _coordinate2
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) $2 = {
  latitude = -122.3582012987846
  longitude = 37.84612098703619
}
```

However printing checking isn't working, also assert runs:

```
p (int)CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(_coordinate1)
(int) $3 = 0
```

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? Any help will be welcomed :)

Comment: are your latitude and longitude mixed-up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know much about what `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` supposed to give you, but according to the docs:

> A coordinate is considered invalid if it meets at least one of the
>   following criteria:
>
> - Its latitude is greater than 90 degrees or less than -90 degrees.
> - Its longitude is greater than 180 degrees or less than -180 degrees.

So since your latitude is less than -90 degrees, I guess the method is just doing their job.

**Edit**: It appears that you just used `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` with wrong parameters. It should be:

```
[_myclassinstance setCoordinate1:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lattitude, mapView.region.center.longitude)];
```

Swap `latitude` and `longitude`.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> A coordinate is considered invalid if it meets at least one of the
>   following criteria:
>
> Its latitude is greater than 90 degrees or less than -90 degrees. Its
>   longitude is greater than 180 degrees or less than -180 degrees.

Looks like your latitude is -122 deg. which is outside of the valid range.